# WYSIWYG in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, wysiwyg, webchromeclient

I've been trying to offer a WYSIWYG HTML editor to my users, from inside my app. It doesn't have to be a fancy WYSIWYG. I just need basic functionality like Bold, Italic, Underline, images, link and some basic formatting (font size, colour, alignment). That should be enough.

The perfect solution would be an open source library, but I haven't been able to find one. So I googled around for a web-based editor that works on Android. I found [Sceditor](http://www.sceditor.com/). This editor works great when I fire up my Android browser (Chrome beta). It SEEMS to work from my webview (see screenshot) as well, but it doesn't.

[image: Sorry for the size!]

As soon as I run the editor from within the app, most functionality stops working. The cursor jumps around randomly, I cannot edit existing text anymore and more weird stuff happens. Basically, it just doesn't work.

Question: How can I get this to work appropriately?

Thanks a LOT in advance!

Comment: "The perfect solution would be an open source library, but I haven't been able to find one" -- here is my work-in-progress library: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit

Comment: Wow! That looks awesome. I'm going to try to implement this right away. Please add it as an answer, because this is probably more than enough for this moment :) Thanks CW!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EditText` is perfectly capable of displaying rich text. It's just that there's no easy way for users -- or even developers -- to really control that formatting. Hence, I've been poking off and on with [a library to deal with this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit), offering a `RichEditText` drop-in replacement for `EditText`. It's still a work-in-progress, and I really need to spend more time on it in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: This covers 80% of my needs in a way native to Android. Thanks! Quick question, before I mark this as accepted. It can't output HTML, can it?

Comment: @VicV: You can use the `Html` helper class, and its `toHtml()` method, to convert a `Spannable` into HTML.

Comment: Perfect! This'll get me going! There are still some minor glitches, but I'll keep an eye on github. Thanks man! Much better answer than I expect when I asked the question!

Comment: (I know I should be asking a new question for this, but I'd prefer to save the trouble, sorry! :) ) I can't seem to be getting my HTML to display into the RichEditText. I've got a string with HTML entities, and `Html.fromHtml()` just results in this: http://i.imgur.com/FrXXmZX.png

Comment: @VicV: If that looks like the actual string of HTML, that has no prayer of working in `RichEditText`. `Html.fromHtml()` handles a couple dozen tags, and that's it: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html `RichEditText` is for this subset of HTML, not for editing arbitrary HTML culled from teh Interwebs.

Comment: Hmm. Must be it. When I use basic HTML instead, it works. I'll try to tone down the fancy HTML. Thanks again, you've helped me a lot.

Comment: @VicV: Note that `TextView`/`EditText`/`RichEditText` can technically handle a few more things than are supported by that tag list. The more precise explanation is that the `Html` helper class can only handle those tags (and even that is just on the decode side -- I haven't examined the encode side). In principle, one could write HTML->`Spannable`->HTML routines that handle a slightly richer set of stuff.

Comment: I guess so, but I think in my case the constraint is perfectly fine. This app is a content editor for other apps, so the listed tags should be more than enough for the near future.

Answer (score 2):

[Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) of Andoird API support content editable of HTML.

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
```

to enable webview editable and then use

```
 webview.loadurl("javascript:....")
```

such as :webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.execCommand('bold', false, null);");
to control editing.

your can see WYSIWYG editing of my application on Android, [WYSIWYG editing of YodaNote 0.4](http://youtu.be/FsdwTZkB-x8)