# It is possible let user insert text and image in a field?

Tags: android

I'm developing an applet user write their journal. In the journal, may having rich text and multiple picture. How can i let user insert text and image in a same field like this.

Is it any available component or libraries to do this?

[image: UI of WordPress]

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114348/wysiwyg-in-android-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't native component to do this because it's a relay specific use case. Some libraries provides WYSIWYG features with picture insertion (like [this one](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android)) but it's not a standard and a full customizable component. This is why it's recommended to make your own component.